# ASP.NET & Custom Globalization

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

Whenever I try to access a website from my ASP.NET application, using the System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString method or even using HtmlAgilityPack to read HTML code from a different website, I come across an issue.

The information I receive is based on my globalization settings (e.g country and language of the site being displayed).

I am trying to force a globalization for the English language and USD currency for every website I will be accessing through my application.

So far I came up with the next configuration within my web.config file:

```
<globalization
    fileEncoding="utf-8"
    requestEncoding="utf-8"
    responseEncoding="utf-8"
    culture="en-US"
    uiCulture="en-US"
/>
```

Sadly it does not seem to do the trick.

**Also, setting the 'AcceptLanguage' header doesn't work either.**

Any suggestions?

Comment: Let me see if I got this straight. You're on a website trying to load up another website, forcing culture?

Comment: @FelipeDeguchi I don't know myself if it's culture I'm trying to force or something completely different. I want to have a USD currency whenever I access a website, and since it's accessing the website from my client it gives me my native currency, instead the USD one. When I run the same code from a server hosted in USA, it gives my the USD currency on the website I'm loading. I do not want to be depended on the server.